# How do i find the sum of a field in Mongo with specific conditions?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection with below documents:

```
_id : "123"
name : "rahul"
age : 40
experience: "10"


_id : "124"
name : "manish"
age : 42
experience: "12"

I want to find the sum of all the ages and also experience:

I am using below query:

db.emp_data.aggregate({
      $group:
        {
          _id: null,
          totalCap: {
            $sum: "$age",
          },
        },
    })
```

But , i am getting empty records. What condition should i put in the _id field?

Comment: Take _some effort_ in formatting your code and question properly. Your "documents" are unformatted and just show field names & values. Your aggregation pipeline is invalid since there's not such thing as "group" - it's `$group` - note the `$` sign. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). After fixing the query, the result for sum of "age" is correctly `82`.

Comment: Aside from the useful recommendation from @aneroid, make sure you are correctly pointing to correct database. By "correct", I mean the documents are correctly located in `emp_data` collection in the correct database.

Comment: I looks like the query works: https://mongoplayground.net/p/egFMbN5rIlJ